# Apply text embedding to external swf

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder

I am using Flash Builder 4 to implement embedded text, what I would like to do is apply this embedded text to a text field in an external SWF (.fla file using Flash CS4).

My code is like so:

```
[Embed(source='//lib//fonts//Tahoma.ttf', fontName='_Tahoma', embedAsCFF="false")]

private var embedString:String; // added for embed font

var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

format.font = "_Tahoma";

// WHEN THIS IS SET TO TRUE THE TEXT DISSAPEARS?
(path to .fla).textLabel_txt.embedFonts = true; 

(path to .fla).textLabel_txt.defaultTextFormat = format;

(path to .fla).textLabel_txt.setTextFormat(format);
```

I have set the fontFamily of the dynamic text field inside the .fla to a custom font and have the AnitAlias set for readability.  The Custom font is set to 'Tahoma'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to embed font as a class:

```
[Embed(source='//lib//fonts//Tahoma.ttf', fontName='_Tahoma', embedAsCFF="false")]
public var EMBED_FONT:Class;
```

And then to register your embeded font :

```
Font.registerFont(EMBED_FONT);
```